# What are recommended Blog hosts for new developers?

Tags: admin, blogs, hosts

Seeking best blog host recommended for new-coming coders. I am classifying myself as entry-level, as I only hobby code for now.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of hosting do you want? Windows or Linux? You can search on Google about the advantages and disadvantages of these two types of hosting. Furthermore, if only for blogs, maybe shared hosting is enough for you. For a newcomer, I strongly recommend that you look for a hosting provider that has a friendly support team. Because you will really need them in your early stages. If you decide to choose Windows hosting, I think asphostportal is suitable for you.